# Trouble with this macro :(

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to program a special user login and Audit Trail, the login makes sheets display in custom order, then I still get

> Error 1004: Method of Visible Object Failed.

Help me please :(

Macro 1 (I have 5 sheets in this book, each one has this macro in them):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Me.Name = "Información"
ThisWorkbook.Protect , True
Application.OnTime Now, "UnprotectBook"
End Sub
```

And Have this one in This Workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
Sheet1.Visible = True
Sheet2.Visible = False
Sheet3.Visible = False
Sheet4.Visible = False
Sheet5.Visible = False
UF_log.Show
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Close()
Sheet1.Visible = False
Sheet2.Visible = False
Sheet3.Visible = False
Sheet4.Visible = False
Sheet5.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Delete
MsgBox "No se tiene permitido insertar nuevas hojas de cálculo", vbExclamation, "Alerta"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

UF log code:

```
Private Sub EnterButton_Click()
Dim Fila, final As Integer
Dim password As Variant
Dim DatoEncontrado


UsuarioExistente = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Users").Range("A:A"), _
    Me.TxtUser.Value)
Set Rango = Sheets("Users").Range("A:A")
  If Trim(TxtUser.Text) = "" Then
MsgBox "Ingreso Usuario", vbExclamation, "Alerta"
TxtUser.SetFocus
  Exit Sub
  End If
  
  If Trim(TxtPassword.Text) = "" Then
MsgBox "Ingreso Contraseña", vbExclamation, "Alerta"
TxtPassword.SetFocus
  Exit Sub
  End If
         
        If UsuarioExistente = 0 Then
        MsgBox "El usuario '" & Me.TxtUser & "' no existe", vbExclamation, "Alerta"
        Exit Sub
        End If
        
         If UsuarioExistente = 1 Then
         DatoEncontrado = Rango.Find(What:=Me.TxtUser.Value, MatchCase:=True).Address
         Contra = CStr(Sheets("Users").Range(DatoEncontrado).Offset(0, 1).Value)
         Estatus = CStr(Sheets("Users").Range(DatoEncontrado).Offset(0, 2).Value)
         
         
              If Sheets("Users").Range(DatoEncontrado).Value = Me.TxtUser.Value And Contra = Me.TxtPassword.Value Then
              MsgBox "Acceso correcto", vbExclamation, "Ok"
              
              If Estatus = "Administrador" Then
              Application.Visible = True
              Sheet1.Visible = True
              Sheet2.Visible = True
              Sheet3.Visible = True
              Sheet4.Visible = True
              Sheet5.Visible = True
              Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = True
              Call Desproteger
              For Fila = 1 To 1000
                            If Sheet4.Cells(Fila, 1) = "" Then
                             final = Fila
                              Exit For
                              End If
                        Next
              Sheet4.Cells(final, 1) = Application.UserName & " accessed via log in " & " at " & Time & " " & Date
              Call Proteger
              End
              Else
                If Estatus = "Fabricación" Then
              Application.Visible = True
              Sheet1.Visible = True
              Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
              Sheet3.Visible = True
              Sheet4.Visible = True
              Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
              Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = True
              Call Desproteger
              For Fila = 1 To 1000
                            If Sheet4.Cells(Fila, 1) = "" Then
                             final = Fila
                              Exit For
                              End If
                        Next
              Sheet4.Cells(final, 1) = Application.UserName & " accessed via log in " & " at " & Time & " " & Date
              Call Proteger
              End
              Else
              Application.Visible = True
              Sheet1.Visible = True
              Sheet2.Visible = True
              Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
              Sheet4.Visible = True
              Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
              Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = False
              Call Desproteger
              For Fila = 1 To 1000
                            If Sheet4.Cells(Fila, 1) = "" Then
                             final = Fila
                              Exit For
                              End If
                        Next
              Sheet4.Cells(final, 1) = Application.UserName & " accessed via log in " & " at " & Time & " " & Date
              Call Proteger
              End
              End If
              End If
         Else
         MsgBox "Datos incorrectos, vuelva a intentar", vbExclamation, "Error"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click()
End
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error? You do have a `UF_log` correct? I don't see one created in any of the code. How does `Workbook_Open()` know what that is?

Comment: Be sure to check out https://rubberduckvba.com for automatic code indenting and static code analysis. It can help you find problems as you go.